# Pin operator in a function head

Tags: elixir

I am reading "Programming Elixir 1.3" (PragPub) and ran across something that doesn't make much sense to me.  On page 42 the author describes closures pointing out that in

```
greeter = fn name -> (fn -> "Hello #{name}" end) end
```

the returned function 'remembers' the value of the provided `name` parameter.  This is the nature of closures.  However, 2 pages later he gives the following example:

```
defmodule Greeter do
  def for(name, greeting) do
    fn
      (^name) -> "#{greeting} #{name}"
      (_) -> "I don't know you"
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why the `name` identifier is pinned in the first function head since it should have the value passed in 'remembered' as part of the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so that it matches on the value of what's contained in `name`, rather than doing a pattern match and rebinding to a new variable called `name`.

Checkout the documentation for the [pin operator](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator), that hopefully helps explain it a bit better.

Comment: I read that already, but I don't see the relationship.  In the documentation, the pattern matching is done by matching the left side with what is on the right side of the match operator.  Are you saying that, without the pin operator, we would be throwing away the value of `name` passed to the `for` function?

Comment: In essence yes. It'll be equivalent to creating a new variable called name in the inner scope which will take the value of whatever was passed into that function. Think of it in terms of what would happen if the variable was named something else at that point. It would still match by taking the value passed in. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: OK.  I was looking at the problem wrong.  In the first example, the value of `name` was never re-bound through a pattern match so the value was maintained in the closure.  In the second example, the value of `name` was rebound to whatever value was passed into the anonymous function due to the pattern matching of the two functions definitions.  This is what is forcing us to use the pin operator.